# how to play video using java?

Tags: java, media-player, media, jmf

I want to play a video in media player using java i used JMF to display the video however it gives me an error in one of the data types i used from the JMF library and here is my code.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    // create a file chooser
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();

    // show open file dialog
    int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);

    if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) // user chose a file
    {
        URL mediaURL = null;

        try {
            // get the file as URL
            mediaURL = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().toURL();
        } // end try
        catch (MalformedURLException malformedURLException) {
            System.err.println("Could not create URL for the file");
        } // end catch

        if (mediaURL != null) // only display if there is a valid URL
        {
            JFrame mediaTest = new JFrame("Media Tester");
            mediaTest.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            MediaPlayer mediaPanel = new MediaPlayer(mediaURL);

            mediaTest.add(mediaPanel);

            mediaTest.setSize(300, 300);
            mediaTest.setVisible(true);
        } // end inner if
    } // end outer if
}
```

the problem is it gives me an error in this lines

```
MediaPlayer mediaPanel = new MediaPlayer(mediaURL);
```

The constructor MediaPlayer(URL) is undefined as the MediaPlayer constructor does not take anything but i need to add url to the mediaplayer to display it in the jframe but i cannot, any help ?

Comment: Post the error message.

Comment: [link](http://imgur.com/a/z4ILO)

Comment: MediaPlayer is class from javax.media.bean.playerbean.MediaPlayer

Comment: Did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11133456/audio-player-using-mediaplayer-class-in-jmf

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`setMediaLocation(location)`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2se/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/apidocs/javax/media/bean/playerbean/MediaPlayer.html#setMediaLocation(java.lang.String)) to specify the location of the media to launch, so try this instead:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPanel = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPanel.setMediaLocation(mediaURL.toString());
```

Alternatively you can use [`setMediaLocator(locator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2se/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/apidocs/javax/media/bean/playerbean/MediaPlayer.html#setMediaLocator(javax.media.MediaLocator)) for the same purpose but a little bit more convenient in case you have an `URL`, the code would then be:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPanel = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPanel.setMediaLocator(new MediaLocator(mediaURL));
```

Comment: the media locator solved the error however when i run it gives me nothing the jframe opens successfully but without the video inside it,,, can you help ?

Comment: JMF is outdated now, you should not rely on it too much, you should rather use the player from Java FX. For JMF, the best I can do is to provide the initial tutorial http://www.deitel.com/articles/java_tutorials/20060422/PlayingVideowithJMF/

Comment: download the source code from [here](http://www.deitel.com/articles/java_tutorials/20060422/PlayingVideowithJMF/Fig21_06_07.zip) especially the `MediaPanel`

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to play a mp4 file , then it is so easy

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("test.mp4"));
```

However, If you want to play it specifically in JFrame
Then keep in mind that JMF is not supporting mp4 format. 
By the way please share your error message.

Answer (score 0):

We can also using ProcessBuilder() to any project or video....

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class MainClass extends JPanel{
    public MainClass(){
        JButton btn1 = new JButton("Button1");
        btn1.setBounds(70, 50, 260, 40);
        JTextField txtProName = new JTextField();
        txtProName.setBounds(100, 50, 200, 40);
        add(btn1);
        add(txtProName);
    }
    public static void main(String[]args){
        JFrame frm = new JFrame();
        frm.getContentPane().add(new MainClass());
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.setSize(200, 300);
        frm.setVisible(true);
    }
}
class bListener implements ActionListener{
    bListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder(txtProName.getText());
            try{
                p.start();
            }catch(IOException ex){
                Logger.getLogger(frm.class.getName()).log(level.SERVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And also we can add JFileChooser() to this project, to choose one between  files to run with it..